# TFS Build extension "VisibleRules" definition in json file

Tags: json, tfs, build

i develope a tfs build extension and I have a question about the "VisibleRule" attribute from input fields in the json file. 
I have the following input field definitions and I want to show the input field in dependence of selected option.

Example:
field1 set visible if option1 or option2 is selected

```js
"inputs": [
       {
         "name": "options",
         "type": "pickList",
         "label": "Options",
         "required": true,
         "options": 
  {
  "Option1": "Option1",
  "Option2": "Option2",
  "Option3": "Option3"
  }
        },
  {
         "name": "Field1",
         "type": "string",
         "label": "Field1",
         "required": true,
         "visibleRule": "options = option1"
        },
  {
         "name": "Field2",
         "type": "string",
         "label": "Field2",
         "required": true,
         "visibleRule": "options = option2"
        }
  ]
```

Can I define an or condition for visibleRule like this?

```js
"visibleRule": "options = option2 && options = option3"
```

Comment: Which build ?Vnext or Xaml?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, refer to this format in [AzureFileCopy](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureFileCopyV1/task.json) task for details:

```
"visibleRule": "ConnectedServiceNameSelector = ConnectedServiceName && Destination = AzureVMs"
```

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. That's why we type answers and setting examples here, at SO instead of copy-pasting links... Other than that - good spot. I've been looking for this for quite a long time.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use an OR condition use " || "

Example:

```
"visibleRule": "extensionVisibility = private || extensionVisibility = privatepreview || extensionVisibility = default"
```

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-tasks/blob/main/BuildTasks/PublishExtension/task.json